# Create exe file from tar.gz in linux

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

I managed to create a .deb file from a source program,tar.gz

how can i create an exe file so that the app can also run on windows?i've searched a lot but didnt manage to find any resources.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com!! But what does this mean? `I managed to create a .deb file from a source program,tar.gz`??

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  A `.tar.gz` isn't a "source program", it's an archive that could contain any number of files.  It's not -- by itself -- somethat that you "run".  What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: it means that i made a deb file from tar.gz.so it may be possible to make exe from deb or from tar.gz,i thought it could be useful to mention.

Comment: *How* did you create a `.deb` file from a `.tar.gz` file?  What was in the `.tar.gz` file?

Comment: i made the program in the IDE and then builded it in tarball, then used a set of steps from the debian documentation on how to transform the source in deb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the program under Windows, you'll need to re-compile it from source using a Windows compiler.  How exactly to re-compile it will differ from program to program.  Check the program's documentation for details or ask its maintainer.  ".deb" files and anything else related to Linux package managers have no meaning in Windows, so you'll need to extract the source from the source .deb or pull it from the appropriate source repository.

Be aware that many Linux programs won't build for Windows with a simple recompile alone.  If they use any external libraries, then those libraries need to be available for Windows as well.  The Cygwin environment may help here.  If there isn't already an official procedure for building that particular program under Windows, then you may have to do the porting work yourself (which is a large enough task that it's well outside the scope of this question).

Comment: Yes.I have builded the program itself in a tar.gz archive with the source files & libraries included,all these in a linux environment,making it installable and usable in that os.My main question is how i can make an exe file of that archive so that i can use it in a setup wizard(which i have installed on my machine) so that it can be used by Windows users.I have seen some ubuntu programs eg evince that use linux libraries that can be installed on windows and was wondering how i can also do that(google was not my friend this time)

Comment: What program is this that you're trying to compile?  Is it a normal open-source program, or is it a program that you have created?

Comment: If you created the program, then you're going to have to port it to Windows manually (which is usually far from trivial).  You'll need to set up a Windows development environment and try to compile the code there.  Without knowing the details of your code I can't predict what exactly this porting process will entail.  You'll just have to try it, see how far you can get, and tweak it to resolve build errors as they appear.